# Push multiple folders to a repo

Tags: git, github

How do I add 2 different folders without the same parent folder into 1 repo?

Basically, I wrote a bunch of code snippets in Haskell and pushed that to the repo.

Now I'm writing Go snippets, and its in a completely different folder on my harddrive. How do I link that to the same repo, so I can push it and keep things organized?
Currrently, when I try to push git is telling me to fetch first. But if I do that, I'll basically have 2 copies of my repo on my harddrive.

Comment: *without the same parent folder*: just change that: put them both into the folder containing the clone of your repo. If you think they shouldn't have the same parent folder, then they shouldn't be in the same repo either.

Answer (score 1):

From your first folder (which is a local git repo, and has been pushed), you can do:

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/second/folder add .

# in case a git status shows haskell files deleted:
git reset *.hs

git commit -m "Add go files"
git push
```

Comment: oh uhm.. actually its basically on different computers. (VMware ubuntu vs window)

Comment: Is there any way for one to access the folder of the other, through a shared mounted drive?